# MySQL indexes optimisation

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a big query with different tables queried with joins and with WHERE CLAUSES.

Now from my understanding the best index to have is to see the *WHERE CLAUSE* and add it as an index

```
select name from Table WHERE name = 'John'
```

We would have an index on the "name" field .

How would we determine the best index to have  if the clause looks like this:

```
WHERE table1.field = 'x' and table2.field = 'y' etc...
```

of course the query is much more complicated than that , just want to know how to proceed and if you guys have a better idea .

Comment: The query is more complicated than that -- _and_ so is the answer.  We can't specify the optimal indexes without knowing how you `JOIN ... ON ...` to connect the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM tA
    JOIN tB WHERE tA.x = tB.y
    WHERE tA.name = 'foo'
      AND tB.name = 'bar'
```

begs for

```
tA: INDEX(name, x)
tB: INDEX(name, y)
```

On the other hand:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM tA
    JOIN tB WHERE tA.name = tB.name
```

needs `INDEX(name)` on both tables.

If `name` is the `PRIMARY KEY` on each table, then those indexes are redundant and should not be added.

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as single index for multiple tables. The first thing you could do, is to create an index for `table1` on `field` and another one for `table2` on `field`. If this still not fast enough, depending on your database schema, you could set a foreign key.

Lastly, you can create a view which contains data from both tables and then index that view. The advantage of a view is to have the data pre-joined which **might** make the query even faster.

Comment: From what i know is that you can't add an index on a mysql view

Comment: I disagree that view will perform better than query....please share a case or documentation if you have.

Comment: You are right, that might not be necessarily true and depends on your data. I was using views to pre-calculate geographical distance between various items (based on just coordinates in the one of the base tables). Updated the answer to not make it hard fact.

Answer (score 0):

**How would we determine the best index to have if the clause looks like this:**

```
WHERE table1.field = 'x' and table2.field = 'y' etc...
```

First of all as you are using join of 2 tables then join fields should be indexed and for better performance these fields should be integer type.

Now try to check which condition is filtering more data means reducing rows and try to create index on that field or composite index on multiple fields (make sure field should be in most left in index which is filtering more data) but index size should not increase too much.

Normally (not always) one table uses single index, so as you are filtering data from multiple tables so you can create index on both tables columns if you are getting sufficient data filteration by these fields.

Further anyone can advise better after seeing your actual query.